# Relation $R$ is $xy\ge1$, and $x\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $y\in\mathbb{Z}$, is $R$ reflexive?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

This is a question from book "Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications".

> 9.1.7
>
> Determine whether the relation R on the set of all integers is reflexive,  symmetric, antisymmetric, and/or transitive,  where(x, y)
> ∈ R if and only if
>
> b) $xy \ge 1.$

The answer provided by the book is: $R$ is symmetric and transitive.

Why isn't $R$ reflexive?

I think $R$ is reflexive because $x$ and $y$ are integers, since $xy \ge 1$, they are positive integers or negative integers, that $xx \ge 1$ should be true, that $R$ should be reflexive.

Comment: Note that we do not have $xy \geq 1$ if one or both of $x, y$ is zero, and zero is an integer.

Comment: If x or y is zero, that `xy≥1` will be false, so (x,y)∉R.

Comment: Yes, exactly that.

Comment: @Freewind: You forgot about $0$, easy to do, it is so small. The relation is not reflexive because $(0,0)\not\in R$. For all $x\ne 0$, $(x,x)\in R$. So reflexivity *almost* holds.

Comment: I understand now! I misunderstood the definition of `reflexive`: `A relation R on a set A is called reflexive if (a, a) ∈ R for every element a ∈ A.`. There is `every element a ∈ R`, so we must consider `0`.

Comment: @OldJohn,could you please make you comment an answer, and I will accept it? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recall that $xRy$ if and only if $(x,y)\in R$, and $R$ is defined to be reflexive if and only if $(x,x) \in R$ for all $x$.

In this case, $0$ is an integer, and the statement $xy \geq 1$ is false if one or both of $x, y$ is zero, so your relation fails to be reflexive.

Answer (score 6):

A relation $\,R\,$ on a set $A$ is  reflexive *if and only if*, for ***every*** element $\,a\in A,\,$ it is true that $\;(a, a) \in R\;$.

In this problem, suppose $x = 0$. Since $\;0 \in \mathbb{Z}$, but $xx = 0\cdot 0 \ngeq 1$, thus $(0, 0) \notin R$, and so the relation fails to be reflexive on the set of integers.

It only takes **one element** as a counterexample to prove the relation on the set *non*-reflexive.

If your relation were defined on the set of *non-zero* integers, then it would be reflexive.